# Java: how to parse a file to get edges for generating graph

Tags: java, parsing

I'm having trouble reading data from file. 
Currently I'm adding edges inside the program, which generates a graph based on lists of edges. However, I want my program to read edges from a file to create a graph (read a .txt file line by line)

The .txt file would look something like this:

```
0, 1
0, 4
1, 2
1, 3
1, 4
2, 3
3, 4
```

The sample code for the program looks like this:

```
import java.util.*; 

class GraphIO { 

    static void addEdge(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer> > adj, 
                        int u, int v) 
    { 
        adj.get(u).add(v); 
        adj.get(v).add(u); 
    } 

    static void printGraph(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer> > adj) 
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < adj.size(); i++) { 
            System.out.println("\nAdjacency list of vertex" + i); 
            for (int j = 0; j < adj.get(i).size(); j++) { 
                System.out.print(" -> "+adj.get(i).get(j)); 
            } 
            System.out.println(); 
        } 
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        int V = 5;
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer> > adj  
                    = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer> >(V); 

        for (int i = 0; i < V; i++) 
            adj.add(new ArrayList<Integer>()); 

        addEdge(adj, 0, 1); 
        addEdge(adj, 0, 4); 
        addEdge(adj, 1, 2); 
        addEdge(adj, 1, 3); 
        addEdge(adj, 1, 4); 
        addEdge(adj, 2, 3); 
        addEdge(adj, 3, 4); 

        printGraph(adj); 
    } 
}
```

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: See @user answer how to fix that file-reading loop. Right now your code just stores how many space-separated words it found in the 'count' variable. Thanks for the edit, questions you display having put effort in are more likely to get answers!

Comment: I still get three error messages: 1.) -File cannot be resolved to a type; 2.) -IOException cannot be resolved to a type. 3.) -reader cannot be resolved.Do you have any ideas why I have this problem?

Comment: That was true, then the only problem seems to be "printGraph(list)". I get: "list cannot be resolved to a variable". How do I tackle that error? I also tried System.out.println(list) but I got the same error message.

Comment: That looks fine, but If I don´t know the number of vertices in the txt.file, is it a simple soultion for that problem? I see that the program crashes if for example int V = 5 but that the actual number of vertices in the .txt.file is 6.

Comment: Yes, both seems to work for me aswell. Thanks for taking your time, I will now accept this answer since it solved the problem! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I added a `List` this time and called `addEdge` correctly this time. Sorry I ignored the method signature last time.

In your while loop, when you read a new line, you can add an edge right there, after the parsing the numbers from the read line:

```
while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
    String[] nums = reader.nextLine().split(", ");
    addEdge(adj, Integer.parseInt(nums[0]), Integer.parseInt(nums[1]));
}
```

You also need a catch after your try.

Side note: I don't think you should be skipping a line, but I don't know if that's a specific thing your program is supposed to do.

Your `addEdge` method should look like this to make sure your `List` is all filled up with `ArrayList`s and you don't get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
static void addEdge(List<List<Integer>> adj, int u, int v) {
  int bigger = (u > v ? u : v) + 1;
  //Keep increasing the size until it's right
  while (adj.size() < bigger) adj.add(new ArrayList<>());
  adj.get(u).add(v);
  adj.get(v).add(u);
}
```

And your main method would have to be changed slightly. Since you don't know the number of vertices, you just make an empty `ArrayList` of default capacity. 
Declaring `adj` as `List<List<Integer>>` is not necessary - you can still use `ArrayList`, but `List` is an interface that other classes implement, and it's not absolutely necessary to use `ArrayList`s here, so I used that.

I also removed the `reader.nextLine()` because you're discarding that data, and that edge doesn't get registered.

```
  List<List<Integer>> adj = new ArrayList<>();

  File input = new File("filename"); //Define the input file with "filename"
  try {
   Scanner reader = new Scanner(input); //read in the file

   while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
    String[] nums = reader.nextLine().split(", ");
    addEdge(adj, Integer.parseInt(nums[0]), Integer.parseInt(nums[1]));
   }
   printGraph(adj);
   reader.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
```

Output:

```
Adjacency list of vertex0
 -> 1 -> 4

Adjacency list of vertex1
 -> 0 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4

Adjacency list of vertex2
 -> 1 -> 3

Adjacency list of vertex3
 -> 1 -> 2 -> 4

Adjacency list of vertex4
 -> 0 -> 1 -> 3
```

However, this program is very dependent on the order of the edges in the `txt` file, so I would rather do it like this. It's not very efficient, it uses Maps and Sets instead of ArrayLists, but it feels clearer to me.

```
static void addEdge(Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> adj, int u, int v) {
  //If it doesn't already exist, add the set of adjacent vertices here
  if (!adj.containsKey(u)) adj.put(u, new HashSet());
  if (!adj.containsKey(v)) adj.put(v, new HashSet());

  adj.get(u).add(v);
  adj.get(v).add(u);
 }

 static void printGraph(Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> adj) {
  for (int u : adj.keySet()) {
   System.out.println("\nAdjacency list of vertex" + u);
   for (int v : adj.get(u)) {
    System.out.print(" -> " + v);
   }
   System.out.println();
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> adj = new HashMap<>();

  File input = new File("filename");
  try {
   Scanner reader = new Scanner(input); //read in the file

   while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
    String[] nums = reader.nextLine().split(", ");
    addEdge(adj, Integer.parseInt(nums[0]), Integer.parseInt(nums[1]));
   }
   printGraph(adj);
   reader.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Okey, but how should I implement this? I guess have to the adjust the complete " public static void main(String[] args)" -part? I don't know how to implement "file input" into my current program.

Comment: Yes, there is a Scanner in the file input reader code, However, I guess I have to rewrite the whole code to implement the "file input reader" instead of adding edges one by one inside the program? I have no idea how to do this...

Comment: I have updated how I implement the file input reader code into my program under "Added_2" in my question. However. this is incorrect. Do you have any suggestions @user ?

Comment: I don't think your code is wrong, however since I still can't generate graphs using input from a .txt file, this is not the full solution. Even though your solution might be correct, I can't implement it. I don't know how to implement the "file input" code to my program to get the expected result.